# VS 2013 stop working after pushing start debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've started a new project in  `C#` and for that I decided to "spoil" my self and upgrading to VS 2013 from 2010 . 
I've just started with a vary simple from application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

and this is the Form code, again vary basic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //RndColor();

    }
    public void RndColor()
    {
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        KnownColor randomColorName = names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
        Color randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
        TestingBut.BackColor = randomColor;


    }

    private void TestingBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Task NewTask = new Task()
        //Control Ctrl = new (Control(sender));
        RndColor();
        if (TestingChk.Checked)
        {
            ScrnMain.AppendText("Test Me");


        }
    }
}
}
```

now comes to issue, after pushing build
I push start and get this problem : multiple Froms are opened and the VS crushes

picture of the crash:

[image]

Please help me! I've googled the crap out of it and can't find nothing. Thank you in advance !

P.S 
לא מגיב  == not responding in Hebrew

Comment: Provide a URL to the image in your question, I'll make it an image.

Comment: I'm new here , can you give me a example so i can edit my Q?

Comment: Just upload the image to dumpyourphoto.com or another image-hosting website and provide the URL. :)

Comment: There's no way this code would open multiple windows. You either haven't shown us the whole code or you have something seriously bugged in Windows. I can't reproduce this with my VS 2013...

Comment: edited my question , now with picture

Comment: @walther the only code I didnt show is the Design which I don't think is related here , what do you think can cause this behavior ?

Comment: It looks like on each `Form.Load` something like `new Form1().Show()` is executed. You can't Google this, you'll have to debug it. Step through the program using Step Over / Step Into and see when the issue occurs.

Comment: @CodeCaster  I've put break point on `Application.Run(new Form1());`
and it doesn't even get to there , same behavior as before

Comment: What happens if you remove all the code that you personally wrote and run it as a blank application?

Comment: @rhughes same phenomenon

Comment: Problem Solved !
I ran through my installed programs , and uninstall any leftovers remains from old version of VS , although its solved I still can point to the source of the problem 

Thanks for the kind helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was multiple visual installation from different version (2008 , 2012 ..)
just erased them , and now all working well